# Find all the polynomials $p \in \mathbb R [X]$ such that $(x+1)p=(p')^2$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, real-numbers

(Where $p'(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$)

Research effort:

what I thought is that given that $(x+1)|(p')^2$ then $(x+1)|(p')$ (I'd like to justify better this, but I don't know how)

Then,

$$p'(x)= (x+1)h(x), h(x) \in \mathbb R$$

Replacing in the original equation,

$$ (x+1)p(x)=(x+1)^2h(x)^2$$

$$p(x)=(x+1)h(x)^2$$

deriving

$$p'(x)=2(x+1)h(x)h'(x)+h(x)^2$$

but $p'(-1)=0$ then $h(-1)=(x+1)k(x), k(x) \in \mathbb R$

finally

$$p(x)=(x+1)(x+1)^2h(x)^2$$

whith $h(x) \in \mathbb R$

Is this ok?

Comment: What you want to "justify better": if a prime element (in an integer domain, at least) divides the power of some element then it divides the element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The $0$ polynomial obviously works. Now look for non-zero polynomials that satisfy our condition. Take such a polynomial $p$, and suppose that $p$ has degree $n$. Then $(x+1)p(x)$ has degree $n+1$, and $(p'(x))^2$ has degree $2(n-1)$. That gives $n=3$.

You observed that $x+1$ divides $p$. Indeed $(x+1)^2$ divides $p$. Thus $p$ has shape $(ax+b)(x+1)^2$. Now you can compute.

Comment: Beat me to it. :D

Comment: You missed $p=0$ although.

Comment: I had started by saying we would look for non-zero polynomials, leaving it to OP to see that the zero polymomial works. Since then I have changed the wording.

Comment: Okay got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

To justify the very first assertion, note that if $x + 1 | (p')^2$, then $-1$ is a root of $(p')^2$; then $-1$ is also a root of $p'$, so $x + 1 | p'$. The final part of the argument isn't clear; you say

$$h(-1) = (x + 1) k(x), k(x) \in \mathbb{R}$$
but $h(-1)$ is a number.

---

For a different approach, note that $0$ is the only constant solution. Otherwise, let $n$ be the degree of $p$. Then $(x + 1)p$ has degree $n + 1$, while $p'$ has degree $n - 1$, so that

$$n + 1 = 2n - 2$$

Rearranging,

$$n + 1 = 2n - 2 \implies n=3$$

So $p$ is either constant, or a cubic.

Comment: Suggested edit: *If* p is constant, p'=0 must imply p = 0.

Comment: little doubt: if degree of $p'$ is $n-1$ shouldn't the degree of $(p')^2$ be $2n-2$ and not $(n-1)^2$?

Comment: @FranckN Yes, you're quite right - I've fixed it now.